# Babel skip logging the transpiled script to console

Tags: reactjs, webpack, yarn-v2, babel-cli

```
yarn run babel -f babel.config.js
```

is logging all the transpiled scripts to the console by default.

Is there an option in Babel to skip logging the transpiled javascript to Console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to prevent `babel` logging thing, you need to set up the `--out-file` and set `--quiet` option:

```bash
// yarn
yarn babel input.js --out-file output.js --quiet
// or with npx
npx babel input.js --out-file output.js --quiet
```